# How do I resolve unmet dependencies related to Mesa/Wayland?

Tags: 13.04, apt, dependencies, wayland

On my Ubuntu 13.04 machine, I used to have the [Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/) enabled and with a recent update it required Wayland as a dependency. This seems to have broken my package system.

I disabled this PPA so when I try to upgrade, I get the following

```
sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
                Recommends: libegl1-mesa-drivers but it is not installed
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8 is installed
 libgbm1 : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 9.3~git1309181129.ec44d5~gd~r) but 9.3~git1309171217.a1b6e6~gd~r is installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-common (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r is installed
 libgtk-3-bin : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I do not dare doing `sudo apt-get -f install` since this will remove a huge amount of packages, including unity, network-manager-gnome, etc.

What should I do?
I tried installing Synaptic (and one of its dependencies, libgtk-3-0) from DEB packages found on Launchpad, but this failed also.

---

I am ready to remove said PPA totally, using ppa-purge. When I try that, the solutions it presents always imply removing Unity, which I do not want.

---

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get check`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
                Recommends: libegl1-mesa-drivers but it is not installed
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8 is installed
 libgbm1 : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not installable
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 9.3~git1309181129.ec44d5~gd~r) but 9.3~git1309171217.a1b6e6~gd~r is installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-common (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r is installed
 libgtk-3-bin : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.6.4-0ubuntu8+gd~r) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: what version if ubuntu are you using?  I strongly suspect the PPA owner is using this PPA in combination with the ricotz PPA which has this version of libwayland (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_shell?dist=raring).  Do you really need this PPA - or is it easier just to ppa-purge the PPA to get back to stock ubuntu?

Comment: Could you add `sudo apt-get check` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was reinstall Ubuntu, since I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-client0_1.2.1-1~r~gd_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-server0_1.2.1-1~r~gd_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-cursor0_1.2.1-1~r~gd_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this does?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `install -f` would like to make me uninstall Unity again. `dist-upgrade` brings the error that the following packages have unmet dependencies: `libgail-3-0` `libgl1-mesa-dev` `libgtk-3-0` `libgtk-3-bin`.